# Bicubic interpolation giving wrong results

Tags: image-processing, bicubic

I'm trying to implement bicubic interpolation for image transformation like scaling and skewing, but the image output seems inaccurate. The interpolated pixels are sometimes overflowing beyond 255.

Here is the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <sal.h>
#define ASSERT _ASSERTE 
template<typename T>
class bicubic_sampler
{
    // use to offset into int 4x4 array to get individual channel 
    #pragma region constants
    static unsigned constexpr x00 = 0;
    static unsigned constexpr x01 = 4;
    static unsigned constexpr x02 = 8;
    static unsigned constexpr x03 = 12;
    static unsigned constexpr x10 = 16;
    static unsigned constexpr x11 = 20;
    static unsigned constexpr x12 = 24;
    static unsigned constexpr x13 = 28;
    static unsigned constexpr x20 = 32;
    static unsigned constexpr x21 = 36;
    static unsigned constexpr x22 = 40;
    static unsigned constexpr x23 = 44;
    static unsigned constexpr x30 = 48;
    static unsigned constexpr x31 = 52;
    static unsigned constexpr x32 = 56;
    static unsigned constexpr x33 = 60;
    #pragma endregion

    T   a00, a01, a02, a03,
        a10, a11, a12, a13,
        a20, a21, a22, a23,
        a30, a31, a32, a33;

public:

    void sample(_In_ UINT32(&pix)[4][4], _In_ T x, _In_ T y, _Inout_ BYTE(&output)[4])
    {
        auto channel_count = 3u; // skip alpha
        for (auto c = 0; c != channel_count; ++c)
        {
            auto p = reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(pix) + c;

            a00 = p[x11];
            a01 = -.5*p[x10] + .5*p[x12];
            a02 = p[x10] - 2.5*p[x11] + 2 * p[x12] - .5*p[x13];
            a03 = -.5*p[x10] + 1.5*p[x11] - 1.5*p[x12] + .5*p[x13];
            a10 = -.5*p[x01] + .5*p[x21];
            a11 = .25*p[x00] - .25*p[x02] - .25*p[x20] + .25*p[x22];
            a12 = -.5*p[x00] + 1.25*p[x01] - p[x02] + .25*p[x03] + .5*p[x20] - 1.25*p[x21] + p[x22] - .25*p[x23];
            a13 = .25*p[x00] - .75*p[x01] + .75*p[x02] - .25*p[x03] - .25*p[x20] + .75*p[x21] - .75*p[x22] + .25*p[x23];
            a20 = p[x01] - 2.5*p[x11] + 2 * p[x21] - .5*p[x31];
            a21 = -.5*p[x00] + .5*p[x02] + 1.25*p[x10] - 1.25*p[x12] - p[x20] + p[x22] + .25*p[x30] - .25*p[x32];
            a22 = p[x00] - 2.5*p[x01] + 2 * p[x02] - .5*p[x03] - 2.5*p[x10] + 6.25*p[x11] - 5 * p[x12] + 1.25*p[x13] + 2 * p[x20] - 5 * p[x21] + 4 * p[x22] - p[x23] - .5*p[x30] + 1.25*p[x31] - p[x32] + .25*p[x33];
            a23 = -.5*p[x00] + 1.5*p[x01] - 1.5*p[x02] + .5*p[x03] + 1.25*p[x10] - 3.75*p[x11] + 3.75*p[x12] - 1.25*p[x13] - p[x20] + 3 * p[x21] - 3 * p[x22] + p[x23] + .25*p[x30] - .75*p[x31] + .75*p[x32] - .25*p[x33];
            a30 = -.5*p[x01] + 1.5*p[x11] - 1.5*p[x21] + .5*p[x31];
            a31 = .25*p[x00] - .25*p[x02] - .75*p[x10] + .75*p[x12] + .75*p[x20] - .75*p[x22] - .25*p[x30] + .25*p[x32];
            a32 = -.5*p[x00] + 1.25*p[x01] - p[x02] + .25*p[x03] + 1.5*p[x10] - 3.75*p[x11] + 3 * p[x12] - .75*p[x13] - 1.5*p[x20] + 3.75*p[x21] - 3 * p[x22] + .75*p[x23] + .5*p[x30] - 1.25*p[x31] + p[x32] - .25*p[x33];
            a33 = .25*p[x00] - .75*p[x01] + .75*p[x02] - .25*p[x03] - .75*p[x10] + 2.25*p[x11] - 2.25*p[x12] + .75*p[x13] + .75*p[x20] - 2.25*p[x21] + 2.25*p[x22] - .75*p[x23] - .25*p[x30] + .75*p[x31] - .75*p[x32] + .25*p[x33];

            auto x2 = x * x;
            auto x3 = x2 * x;
            auto y2 = y * y;
            auto y3 = y2 * y;

            auto dd = (a00 + a01 * y + a02 * y2 + a03 * y3) +
                (a10 + a11 * y + a12 * y2 + a13 * y3) * x +
                (a20 + a21 * y + a22 * y2 + a23 * y3) * x2 +
                (a30 + a31 * y + a32 * y2 + a33 * y3) * x3;
            //ASSERT(dd <= 0xff);  // this is overflowing beyond 255

            auto finalValue = (std::min)(255.0, dd);
            output[c] = static_cast<BYTE>(finalValue);
        }
    }
};

template<typename T, typename Matrix>
void transform_pixels(_In_  T* src, _Inout_ T* dest, _In_ const int width, _In_ const int height, _In_ const Matrix & mat)
{

    auto bc_sampler = bicubic_sampler<double>{};

    const ptrdiff_t channelCount = 4;

    for (auto y = 0; y != height; ++y)
    {
        for (auto x = 0; x != width; ++x)
        {
            auto p0 = point<double>(x, y);   //original point
            auto p = transform_point(mat, p0);  // calculate the tranform point after applying matrix mul, like scale, skewing, rotation

            auto pf = point < std::ptrdiff_t >(pt_floor(p));
            auto frac = point < double >{ p.x - pf.x, p.y - pf.y };

            if (pf.x < 0 || pf.y < 0 || pf.x >= width || pf.y >= height)
            {
                continue;
            }

            BYTE mp[4]{};  // one pixel transformed output

            auto loc = (src + (pf.y * width + pf.x) * channelCount);

            auto stride = width * channelCount;
            if (pf.x - 1 >= 0 && pf.y - 1 >= 0 && pf.x + 2 < width && pf.y + 2 < width)
            {
                UINT32 neig4x4[4][4] = {};

                // store the 16 neighbours
                neig4x4[0][0] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc - (1 * stride) - channelCount);
                neig4x4[0][1] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc - (1 * stride));
                neig4x4[0][2] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc - (1 * stride) + channelCount);
                neig4x4[0][3] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc - (1 * stride) + 2 * channelCount);

                neig4x4[1][0] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc + (1 * stride) - channelCount);
                neig4x4[1][1] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc + (1 * stride));
                neig4x4[1][2] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc + (1 * stride) + channelCount);
                neig4x4[1][3] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc + (1 * stride) + 2 * channelCount);

                neig4x4[2][0] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc + (2 * stride) - channelCount);
                neig4x4[2][1] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc + (2 * stride));
                neig4x4[2][2] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc + (2 * stride) + channelCount);
                neig4x4[2][3] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc + (2 * stride) + 2 * channelCount);

                neig4x4[3][0] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc + (3 * stride) - channelCount);
                neig4x4[3][1] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc + (3 * stride));
                neig4x4[3][2] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc + (3 * stride) + channelCount);
                neig4x4[3][3] = *reinterpret_cast<INT32*>(loc + (3 * stride) + 2 * channelCount);

                // mp is interoplated pixel 
                bc_sampler.sample(neig4x4, frac.x, frac.y, mp);

                auto dst = reinterpret_cast<void*>(dest + (y * width + x) * channelCount);  // at what location in dest to copy pixel from the source
                memcpy_s(dst, channelCount, mp, channelCount);
            }
            else
            {
                auto dst = reinterpret_cast<void*>(dest + (y * width + x) * channelCount);
                memcpy_s(dst, 4, loc, 4);  // copy the original 
            }

        } // for x
    } // for y
}
```

Output is for zoom transformation

Bilinear output:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVeoF.jpg]

Bicubic output
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDKsh.jpg]

Comment: It's the nature of the bicubic formula that it can overflow or underflow. You need to use clamping to keep the values within valid limits. See e.g. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fastest-way-to-clamp-an-integer-to-the-range-0-255